# Delete rows with two conditions

Tags: r

My matrix in R:

```
"V1""V2""V3"
200 0.4  0.5
201 0.4  0.0
202 0.0  0.0
204 0.0  0.1
```

My goal is to only delete the rows where `V2` AND `V3` is zero, i.e row number `202`. When I try

```
df[!(df[,2] == 0) & !(df[,3] == 0),]
```

It also removes `201` and `202`.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: You need `df[!(df[,2]==0 & df[,3]==0),]`

Comment: Please use `dput(yourMatrix)` to present your data, i.e. edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42924967/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic should be both 'V2' and 'V3' are zero then delete it.  So, we need to use `&` for both 0 and then negate it to find only those rows that are not both 0

```
df[!(df[,2]==0 & df[,3]==0),]
#   V1  V2  V3
#1 200 0.4 0.5
#2 201 0.4 0.0
#4 204 0.0 0.1
```

---

This can be also done with `rowSums`

```
df[rowSums(df[,-1]!=0) >0,]
```

Comment: nice. This works also: `subset(df, abs(V2)+abs(V3)!=0)`

Comment: First suggestion works perfect. Should have thought of that. Thank you.